# scrollview and linearlayout weird view

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

I am trying to make the food menu to scrollable but once i add it, it become like in the image. Before I add the scrollview, I cant view my back button in my screen eventhough I have added it. this is my weird code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/foodbg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/backToMenu"
            android:text="Back" >
        </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: try to give fix hight to Button instad of wrap_content

Comment: remove scrollview and try to use setFooter of listview with different layout xml file having button there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, you can use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead of LinearLayout.

In such case you should place your button at the bottom of the layout. After that place your list at the top of the layout and above the button. RelativeLayout has special xml-attributes to help you do this. After that you do not need a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/backToMenu"
            android:text="Back" >
        </Button>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Try to implement above code

Comment: Nope... cant work. Same condition as in image